# Extracting specific row values from derby Database

Tags: sql, derby

I have below table and I need to filter the the row based on the values from RESULT column. When the Result is 1 then Pick that row.If result is 0 then pick the last row of that particular country.

```js
Country        Order START_TIME        TARGET REQUEST  RESPONSE RESULT
UK   1 17/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
UK   2 17/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
UK   3 17/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
GERMANY   1 17/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 1
SINGAPORE  1 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
SINGAPORE  2 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
SINGAPORE  3 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 1
JAPAN   1 15/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
JAPAN   2 15/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
JAPAN   3 15/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
AUSTRALIA  1 16/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
AUSTRALIA  2 17/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
AUSTRALIA  3 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
CANADA   1 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
CANADA   2 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
VIETNAM   1 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 1
THAILAND  1 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
MALYASIA  1 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
MALYASIA  2 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
```

Below is what I need from above table.I need to do this in Derby.

Meta data of the table
Country     - VARCHAR
Order       - INTEGER
Start Time  - TIMESTAMP
TARGET      - VARCHAR
REQUEST     - CLOB
RESPONSE    - CLOB
RESULT      - CHAR

```js
Country  Order  START_TIME  TARGET REQUEST   RESPONSE  RESULT
UK   3 17/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
GERMANY   1 17/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 1
SINGAPORE  3 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 1
JAPAN   3 15/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
AUSTRALIA  3 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
CANADA   2 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
VIETNAM   1 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 1
THAILAND  1 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
MALYASIA  2 18/03/2015 15:45 null <XML> content <XML> content 0
```